# UAE Tourist Visa validity and how many days I'm allowed to stay?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel, uae

I'm an Indian and my brother has been working in Sharjah around ten years. It is the first time I'm travelling abroad. He arranged me a tourist visa of 60 days validity and I can stay there up to 39 days (as stated by the visa agent). I should leave on the 40th day.

But in India my travel ticket agent said that I can stay there up to 29 days and I should leave on the 30th day.

I have added my visa image below.
[image: Redacted UAE Tourist Visa]

Could someone please clear up the confusion for me?

Comment: How long a visa did you apply for? And how long did you get?

Comment: What does the visa say?

Comment: The visa in your passport should indicate the date you need to leave? Could you perhaps include a photo of the visa (delete any personal info, of course)

Comment: This is an eVisa. The visa will be stamped in to his passport.

Answer (score 4):

The document you posted states that it is an

> Entry Permit - New - **Tourist Visa**

Since you are going to be entering in Sharjah, I consulted the site of [Sharjah Airport](http://www.sharjahairport.ae/visitor-information/visa-information).

I also consulted the right hand side of the document you posted.

**Either**

> 1- Entry permit (Visit): validity (60) days from date of issue.
>   (a) Long stay visit for 90 days not extendable. (b) Short stay visit for (30) days not extendable.

**or**

> 5- Entry permit (Tourism): validity (60) days from date of issue - duration of stay (30) days from day of entry and extendable on time for a similar period.

One of the above apply to you.

Whichever of the above applies to you, the follow is certain:

- **60 days after the date of issue is the latest you can enter Sharjah**
- **At the very least you have 30 days** after entering the country to leave i.e. you should leave on the 30th day at the latest
- Upon entering Sharjah, you can enquire about whether you can extend your stay for an additional 30 days (as per point 5)

Answer (score 3):

You can enter any airport in UAE
The day you enter, from that day the date is counted and you have 40 days which is extendable to another 20 days after paying the XXX amount to your travel/tourism company from where you got the visa. If you over stay you pay the penalty

Happy journey

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  An oficial reference would go a long way to make it a good answer.